# Adding vertices, edges and ports using JGraph

Tags: java, swing, data-structures, directed-acyclic-graphs, jgraph

I want to add new vertices and edges and create a graph using JGraph Library. I always get this **java.lang.NullPointer** exception. I have created a class function createvertex to create new cells/vertices and drawing edges my connecting to ports. But the port is always shown as null even when I haven't declared it as null. Below is my code. Is anything wrong in my code?

```
public class HelloWorld {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    // Construct Model and Graph
    GraphModel model = new DefaultGraphModel();
    GraphLayoutCache view= new GraphLayoutCache(model,new DefaultCellViewFactory());

    JGraph graph = new JGraph(model,view);

    // Control-drag should clone selection
    graph.setCloneable(true);

    // Enable edit without final RETURN keystroke
    graph.setInvokesStopCellEditing(true);

    // When over a cell, jump to its default port (we only have one, anyway)
    graph.setJumpToDefaultPort(true);

    // Insert all three cells in one call, so we need an array to store them
    DefaultGraphCell[] cells = new DefaultGraphCell[5];
    DefaultPort[] port = new DefaultPort[4];

    // Create Hello Vertex
    cells[0] = createVertex("Hello", 20, 20, 40, 20, Color.BLACK, true);

    port[0].setParent(cells[0]);

    // Create World Vertex
    cells[1] = createVertex("World", 140, 140, 40, 20, Color.ORANGE, true);
    cells[1].add(port[1]);
    cells[1].add(port[2]);
    port[1].setParent(cells[1]);
    port[2].setParent(cells[1]);

    cells[3]=  createVertex("Optical Cards",150,150,20,40,Color.GREEN, true);
    cells[3].add(port[3]);
    port[3].setParent(cells[3]);


    // Create Edge
    DefaultEdge[] edge = new DefaultEdge[2];

    // Fetch the ports from the new vertices, and connect them with the edge
    edge[0].setSource(cells[0].getChildAt(0));
    edge[0].setTarget(cells[1].getChildAt(0));

    cells[2] = edge[0];

    edge[1].setSource(cells[1].getChildAt(1));
    edge[1].setTarget(cells[3].getChildAt(0));

    cells[4]=edge[1];

    // Set Arrow Style for edge
    int arrow = GraphConstants.ARROW_CLASSIC;
    GraphConstants.setLineEnd(edge[0].getAttributes(), arrow);
    GraphConstants.setEndFill(edge[0].getAttributes(), true);

    GraphConstants.setLineEnd(edge[1].getAttributes(), arrow);
    GraphConstants.setEndFill(edge[1].getAttributes(), true);

    // Insert the cells via the cache, so they get selected
    graph.getGraphLayoutCache().insert(cells);

    // Show in Frame
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.getContentPane().add(new JScrollPane(graph));
    //frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

public static DefaultGraphCell createVertex(String name, double x,double y,double w,double h, Color bg, boolean raised) {

    // Create vertex with the given name
    DefaultGraphCell cell = new DefaultGraphCell(name);

    // Set bounds
    GraphConstants.setBounds(cell.getAttributes(), new Rectangle2D.Double(
            x, y, w, h));

    // Set fill color

        GraphConstants.setGradientColor(cell.getAttributes(), Color.orange);
        GraphConstants.setOpaque(cell.getAttributes(), true);

    // Set raised border
    if (raised)
        GraphConstants.setBorder(cell.getAttributes(), BorderFactory
                .createRaisedBevelBorder());
    else
        // Set black border
        GraphConstants.setBorderColor(cell.getAttributes(), Color.black);

    // Add a Port
    DefaultPort port = new DefaultPort();
    cell.add(port);

    return cell;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DefaultPort[] port = new DefaultPort[4];




// Create Hello Vertex
cells[0] = createVertex("Hello", 20, 20, 40, 20, Color.BLACK, true);

port[0].setParent(cells[0]);  //   <---------- port[0] is null here, so you 
                              //               cannot call setParent()
```

Just because you initialized the port *array* doesn't mean that you can simply use the first `DefaultPort` element in the array.  You need to populate the array with valid, non-null `DefaultPort` objects before trying to dereference an item in the array.

Comment: Can you explain how so??